# Small problem with Dedekind Cut definition

Tags: real-analysis

There are four properties that a Dedekind Cut must satisfy. I have a small issue with property 3:

$x, y \in \mathbb{Q}, (x < y) \land (y \in A)\implies x \in A.$

Why is the condition merely that $x < y$ and not $x \leq y$? If you take the contrapositive you find:

$ x \notin A \implies (x \geq y) \lor (y \notin A)$

But in the case that we take $y \in A$, that leaves

$ x \notin A \implies (x \geq y)$

So the implication says that $x$ can be equal to $y$ and yet not in the set $A$, while $y$ is.

I must have done something wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: My concern, I suppose, is that it says $\geq$ and not just $>$.

Comment: The conclusion I got is logical, but it stems from the property I started with. My question is why does the property say $x<y$ and not $x \leq y$

Comment: Great point. I was bothered by $x \notin A \implies (x > y) \lor (x = y)$, but the more I think about it, I think that the case of $x = y$ is another way of saying $y \notin A$, and so when I made the assumption that $y \in A$ and removed it from the consequent, I should have also removed $x = y$. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: You were a great help, thank you.

Comment: @bof Why didn't you post this as an answer instead of as a comment?